# How to grab the Unix command that I had run using Perl script?

Tags: perl, unix

As I am still new to Unix and Perl, I'm finding a simple and direct method to grab the Unix command that I had run using Perl script.

What I know is "history" can track back the commands that I had run, but it is not working in Perl using back ticks `history` to run it.

I tried to put "history > filename" in vi text editor in a temporary file, use command "source" it, and it works, but command "source" also not working in Perl script using back ticks.

Can anyone guide me about my problems? direct me to correct method to solve my problems? T.T

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Shells (well, bash and tcsh, anyway, your shell might, but probably doesn't, vary) only save command history in interactive mode. Commands run in a subshell by a perl script won't be added to the history file.

Comment: there's a lot of additions available via CPAN. None of them are related (including readline support for cpan> shell), and perl shell (psh) isn't related here too.. but one day we'll see completely integrated perl shell.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the history of commands that were run by the user in interactive mode:

```
$data_file = "~/.bash_history";
open(DAT, $data_file) || die("Could not open file!");
@fileData = <DAT>;
close(DAT);
foreach $command (@fileData) {
    # Do things here.
}
```

As mentioned by Wobble, though, this history file will not include commands run from a Perl script - you'll have to have the script append the command to a file when it runs it, thus creating it's own history file (or, append it to `~/.bash_history`, which will have it share the history file with interactive shells).

Comment: I see. Now what if I want to write a Perl script to grab the history of Unix commands? Which means write a Perl scripts that has the same function as Unix Command "history"?

Comment: I tried to use tcsh history but the history does not contain latest Unix commands. The latest will only be available after i close the current xterm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the perl script (that is, you can change it), you can simply write each command run in the perl script to a chosen text file:

```
sub run_program 
{
    my $program = shift;
    open PROGS, ">>my-commands.txt", or die $!;
    print PROGS $program."\n";
    `$program`;
    close(PROGS);
}
```

then just run `run_program($command) every time you wish to run a command in the script.